# How to set background color while selecting row of NSOutlineView in swift for macos

Tags: swift, macos

I am new in macos development in swift. how to add background color on selected cell of NSOutlineView in swift?

Comment: Do you want to change the selection color or do you want to remove the selection color and add a background color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1**

You can conform to **NSOutlineView Delegate** and can implement **outlineViewSelectionDidChange** method that calls on row selection.

```
extension ViewController: NSOutlineViewDelegate {
    
    func outlineViewSelectionDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
        // Get selected row
        if let row = yourOutlineView.rowView(atRow: yourOutlineView.selectedRow, makeIfNecessary: false) {
            // Change background Color
            row.wantsLayer = true
            row.layer?.backgroundColor = .black
        }
    }
}
```

**Method 2**

You can also control the selection highlight from Storyboard:
If you set the Highlight to **Regular**, it will auto-show the selection color.

[image]

Comment: What if multiple selection is switched on? How do you remove the color from the previous selected rows?

Comment: @Willeke I've updated the answer. Please have a look.

Comment: When is the color removed from the deselected rows?

Comment: @Willeke if you're using Storyboard's approach, it will auto remove the color from the deselected row on the new row selection.

Comment: hi M Afham, thanks for your answer its worked , but if we select another row then that previous color doesn't clear

Comment: @Ashkar I'm glad to help you. Which method are you using 1 or 2 ?

Comment: hi M Afham I used 1st method

Comment: @Ashkar try the second one also.

Comment: ok I will try. anyway thank you